# jquery: unexpected token C using ember

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ember.js

Here's my error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token C
    at Object.parse (native)
    at jQuery.parseJSON (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:8219:14)
    at ajaxConvert (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:8501:19)
    at done (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:8962:15)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:9378:9)
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. I'm able to pull data from my backend json api with no problems, but when I try to save data, I just get that jquery error. I'm using the following call:

```
addObject(newObject) {
  newObject.save().then(() => this.transitionTo('page.index'));
}
```

I've read the jquery error has to do with the fact that it's trying to parse a json object into json, but since this is being done by ember, I'm not sure if I'm missing a step somewhere.

If anyone has any ideas of the right direction to look, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Check the browser console to see what the HTTP response actually contains. The error is coming from the code that parses the JSON response.

Comment: Check the network tab ;)  You are likely returning garbage on the save.

Comment: That was it. The backend was returning a 201 response, but without the object it created. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a syntax error thrown while parsing JSON.

Possibly your json is not valid. Check and validate your json. 
You can look your server response from your network tab or by using browser plugins such as [Advanced Rest Client](http://chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo/RestClient.html). This plugin also shows it is a valid json or not.

You can validate your json online by using [such sites](http://jsonlint.com/).